# Unable to successfully upload a file via Slack API

Tags: slack

I'm unable to successfully upload a file even using Slacks [`file.upload`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload/test) tester mechanism here:  https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload

I've applied a Slack app token, channel name, and chosen a file, but get the following result:

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "missing_scope",
    "needed": "files:write:user",
    "provided": "identify,incoming-webhook"
}
```

I then created a new app, and ensured that files: write was in scope (it wasn't in the previous app).  Now, I get a different error:

```
 {
    "ok": false,
    "error": "not_in_channel"
}
```

As a test to confirm that the channel name was ok, I subsequently tried a nonexistent channel name, and the error indicated 'channel_not_found', so the channel name I used should be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to invite the app that you created into the slack channel. Example:

```
@AppBot
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and fixed it by adding the Slack app to the channel

I guess there are many ways to add it;
I just opened the corresponding channel I was trying to "files.upload" to, and clicked the "Add an app" link at the really top of the channel history: [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Before posting a message, reacting to any message or uploading files you need to open a conversation with the channel. You can also do it programmatically and achieve this with the help of API (https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.open)

Comment: I think he is attempting to upload from external app to Slack.

Comment: Helllo.  Yes, I'm trying to upload a file from an external app to Slack.